# Mapbox - Update data-driven styling in session

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

There are several [tutorials](https://www.mapbox.com/help/gl-dds-map-tutorial/) on data-driven styling on Mapbox's site, but none of them address how to update an existing data-driven style (created in Mapbox Studio) in-session. For example, say I want to create a choropleth of US states, colored by area.  User then selects 'color by population' and the color of the states update accordingly.

I've found some [resources](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/) that would allow one to achieve this by adding the geojson of all the states and then doing `map.addLayer`, however the geojson I'm working with (census tracts) is too massive to add to the front-end, so I needed to change the data-driven styling of an existing layer (or find a similar work-around). The data has to be a persisted tileset from mapbox studio, with user updating the data coloration based on geojson properties.

Any ideas or examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Updating data-driven styling at run-time is straightforward. You simply call `map.setPaintProperty`.

I usually implement this with one function that generates the property value. Something like this:

```
function fillColorByPopulation(min, max) {
    return {
        property: 'pop',
        stops: [
            [min, 'red'],
            [max, 'blue']
        ],
        type: 'exponential'
    }
}
function updateStyle(prop) {
    if (prop === 'population') {
        map.setPaintStyle('regions', 'fill-color', fillColorByPopulation(data.minpopulation, data.maxpopulation));
    } else {
        map.setPaintStyle('regions', 'fill-color', 'transparent');
    }
}
```

I generally don't create any data-driven styles within Mapbox Studio. It's simpler to create them all in Javascript.

Comment: Where is the data being referenced? It's not clear to me where `data` is used in the coloring outside of setting the stops. In other words, is this assuming that the data is already appended to the tileset?

Comment: Sorry, it's kind of pseudo-code. Generally, my tilesets exist in mapbox.com, but I compute some statistics separately, with mins, maxes, color bins, etc.